# MySQL Query For Getting Random Questions

Tags: mysql

I have two tables named categories and questions. I need help in writing a query to get random questions. If there are 10 questions , first one will be from first category, second from second category and it continues like that until 10 questions can be displayed. My table structure looks like this

categories
id    |   name

1     |   php

2     |   jQuery

3     |   MySQL

questions
id | question | ans1 |  ans2 | catid | correct

1  | q1       | a1   |  a2   | 1     | a1

2  | q2       | a1   |  a2   | 3     | a1

The query I have is this

```
select * from questions where category_id=$category_id ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 12
```

Comment: this is basically just a variation of the "top N per group" problem...

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problems using my formula. It may be hard but I solve it.
You can try....

//Code starts here

```
//Get maximum value of category id
    $cid = "select * from category";//Getting category id
    $cid = mysqli_query($con,$cid);//Run the query
    $v = array();//Create an array
    while($d = mysqli_fetch_array($max)){
        array_push($v,$d['id']);//Push all id to the array.
    }
    //Get single key form the array randomly with php  array function array_rand().
    $rand = array_rand($v,1);
    $rand = $v[$rand];//Ultimately get the random category id.

    //Now use the category id in where clause.
    $sql = "select * from questions where category_id=$rand  LIMIT 12";
    $sql = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    while($d = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){//$d = data
        echo $d['id'].'. '.$d['question'].'<br>';//Display the questions randomly with multiple questions if exists.
    }
```

//Code ends
Thanks.

Comment: I think the first variable is not $cid, it is $max